# Alternative to fs.readFile to load Handlebars template when using res.json in Express

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I'm aiming to provide a simple live api endpoint (using `res.json()`) in an Express 4 application I'm building which compiles Handlebars templates alongside data and returns a string which then replaces HTML client side.

The issue I'm having is that currently I'm having to use `fs.readFile()` to read the Handlebars content of the template when I'd prefer to use the same mechanism as what's used to display a general view. Is this possible somehow?

Here's a basic example;

data endpoint (json):

```
{
  "title": "Page Title"
}
```

template.hbs

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

live endpoint (json)

```
{
  "tpl": "<h1>Page Title</h1>
}
```

functionality within my route response

```
var api = {};

fs.readFile('template.hbs', 'utf8', function(err, tpl) {

  var template = hbs.compile(tpl);

  // data here is the value returned from the data endpoint above
  api.tpl = template(data);

  res.json(api);

});
```

There may not even be a need for me to worry about this as perhaps this is all Handlebars is doing under the hood but I'm just wondering if there's a simpler method I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`express-handlebars`](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) to use Handlebars as your rendering engine. Just do this:

```
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');

...

app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({/* config */}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Now your templates will render using handlebars, assuming you've passed in the right [config options](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#api) for your app. Now you can just use the ordinary [Express API](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html), like so:

```
...

res.render('template', data, (err, html) => {
  api.tpl = html;
  res.json(api);
});
```